# Backslash being added to Session Variables in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, session-variables

I have two array Session variables for my test.  One is a group of answers the other is a group of questions.  Upon submitting the form and going to the page where the test is graded one of my session arrays maintains its form while the other adds a backslashes () and messes up the code.

So one Session array looks like `\[y'=x\]` (which is the way it should look) and the other looks like `\\[y\'=x\]` (with added backslashes)

The only really difference is where the information comes from, the one that works comes from a database directly, the one that does not comes from a form input that gets its A,B,C,D options from the database. So all options come from the same database there is just a middle man in the one that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, it may be solve your problem.
I am not 100% sure

```
$name = "O'Reilly & Associates";
$name = wp_slash($name);
echo $name;
```

Generally in PHP whenever you want to add '   in the string, You need to add string operators like backslash \ and wordpress handles it by default.
So you are getting that \ added automatically.
Try with **wp_slash()**, It may helps you to solve problem.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't realize my own backslashes had been removed! so the problem isn't with the " ' " it is with the " \ " itself.  As I need to have some backslashes since I am using MathJax